# Do all microcontrollers from one family have the same processor core?

Tags: microcontroller

When we say “**family**” in the context of a micro-controller do we mean all the micro-controller models under the same family name share exactly the same processor core?

For example ATmega128, ATtiny12 and ATmega16 are all in the same family namely Atmel’s **AVR 8 bit family**. Can we then say then the thing makes them the same family is their CPU and that is **exactly the same?**

Do AVR 8 bit and AVR 32 bit families have different processors?

Answer (score 3):

AVR is a bit of a weird example because it's a single-vendor CPU core -- it's only present in certain parts made by Microchip (formerly Atmel). That being said, I believe you are correct that the parts you mentioned all have very similar processor cores; the differences between those parts are primarily in the peripherals and memory size.

A better example of the distinction between a microcontroller family and a processor core is in ARM microcontrollers. There are many families of ARM microcontrollers (ST STM32, Atmel SAMD, NXP LPC, and many others -- some of which are divided into many subfamilies as well) but a much smaller number of ARM processor cores (Cortex-M0, M4, M7, etc), all of which are licensed from Softbank (formerly ARM).

> Do AVR 8 bit and AVR 32 bit families have different processors?

Yes. AVR8 and AVR32 are almost completely unrelated, beyond that they were both designed by Atmel.

Comment: Isn't the same true of PICs?  ARM is the more special case.

Comment: There are plenty of other processor cores which are shared across vendors -- 8051, Power/PowerPC, and MIPS all come to mind, and I'm sure there are a bunch of more obscure ones I don't know the names of offhand.

Comment: @duskwuff I didn't realize the PowerPC was licensed. I thought it was just Motorola. I think the 68000 and Coldfire might be licensed as well.

Comment: Minor detail, but Atmel was bought out by Microchip. The big fish eat the little fish, yet likely it was a big boost for Atmel.

Comment: Are all those licensed by the originator, like ARM, or are they clones?  Regardless, an in-house processor is hardly a weird case.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and comments. The mentioned ARM families are ST STM32, Atmel SAMD, NXP LPC. But do these families differ a lot when learning to program them. For example if I spend so much time on to learn SAM3 family by using Arduino Due board as start; after many years will it be hard to switch and learn a uC from STM32 family? I have no community or friends to ask such experience related question so that's why I ask this here.

Comment: I don't think it's difficult after you know what you're doing. It's more familiarity so you have better context of things and know of what you need to do and know what to look for. It's just really tedious getting a new MCU up and running.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say "exactly" the same code as much as "the processors are developed with migration between them in mind". "Family" seems to be a loose term so treat it accordingly.

The STM32 microcontrollers are a family. And within this family are different series such as STM32F3, STM32F4, STM32F7, STM32H7.But they certainly do not share the same core, although their are similarities between the cores and some cores are super sets of other cores.

Members of the same series (also appears to be a loose grouping) do share the same core (except for multi-core versions where the asymmetric core may or may not be present) and can more-or-less run each other's code. Just the peripherals are different (or sometimes an extra processor is present).

Comment: Is there any term where two uC share exact same core and code compatible?

Comment: I don't think there is a strict term. But it should be fairly obvious from examining the MCU datasheets. At least it is for the STM32. I think it's safe to assume that the processors should share mostly the same part number though.

Comment: Why they don’t stick with same core or architecture ect. there are zilliions and how can one learn them all. Every day they change something and one needs to relearn the new instruction set ect. This is mind buggling makes things ugly. I lose my appetite to learn. Sorry for my ignorant comment.

Comment: Because different applications have different needs. It sounds like you are coding in assembler? It had not occured to me you might be talking about assembler and not something like C/C++.

Comment: It gets more complicated still, because there are parts from *different* vendors the share the *same* ARM Cortex-M0+ core, but have different peripherals, memories, and electrical aspects.

Comment: @atmnt Yeah. Even with a higher level language it can be a PITA to change from one processor to another even if the core is the same because the peripherals are different and requires different set up code. They try to minimize this within a company's line of products to not piss you off, but if you're coding in assembler then you have a whole second thing to deal with.

Comment: No not assembly. I have very little experience with AVR 8 bit. I was planning to learn ARM but too many differences and looks harder and less community yet people say it is the future.

Comment: Well, take comfort in the fact that at least within a single company's line of products, they try to at least make their peripherals (including peripherals that are advanced version of other peripherals) as similar as possible so code can be mostly re-used. And that they try to make their cores (at least those within the same migration line) similar so that customers can migrate from less powerful cores to more advanced cores without having to re-learn everything. You don't learn instruction sets with a higher level language anyways. You just need to get familiar with the registers.

Comment: @atmnt After all, each time you have to completely re-learn one of their products there is an equal opportunity for you to jump ship and learn someone else's product. That's just bad business.

Comment: You wrote “Members of the same series do share the same core” Is there standard naming for indicating same series? Can you give an example?

Comment: @atmnt I can only tell you ST's standard. So STM32 just refers to their 32-bit ARM core microcontrollers that use the ARM's line of Cortex Cores. Then you have STM32xx where xx denotes the "series" which determines the core being used. So STM32F3, STM32F4, STM32F7, and STM32H7 all use different ARM Cortex cores. ARM made their various Cortex cores are made with migration in mind so the instruction sets of the more powerful cores are supersets of the less powerful cores.

Comment: Then there are STM32FxxYYY where YYY determines the specific features on of chip such as core speed and peripherals. Most peripherals at this point are shared but there are specialized ones that are not. Then you have STM32FxxYYY____ where ____ determines the memory size, packaging, etc but are all basically the same processor with the same peripherals at that point. If you follow through their website for a particular part, you can see the hierarchy very clearly as you move from page to page: https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32-32-bit-arm-cortex-mcus.html

Answer (score 1):

The word "family" is not a technical term in this context, so it has no fixed, standard meaning. Anybody can use the word "family" to mean anything they want.

The only way you can be sure of compatibility between processor cores is is there is a published specification for the processor instruction set and architecture. That's one of big advantages of using one of the ARM processor cores...if you know how to write code for a Cortex-M3 processor you can write code for a Cortex-M3 from TI, NXP, or whoever. ARM maintains specification documents for the Cortex-M3 architecture and anyone who sells a "Cortex-M3" must conform to those specifications.

Comment: In practice, what the core is tends to matter less than what the *peripherals* are.  There are a few cases where having an idea of how the core works is important, but that tends to be edge cases and debugging, and knowledge of particular gotchas; generally most of the core-specifics are taken care of by the tools; while the peripheral operation is where thought has to go.   And in terms of differences within say the variety of ARM cores this only quite rarely requires thought.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I agree, but OP asked specifically about the "processor core". I actually thought it was a silly question but I wanted to say something about architecture standards.